# MQTT client connecting only when Console.ReadLine is Present

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asynchronous, mqtt

I am trying to connect to a MQTT broker through a c# console app and then publish it, accessing the message from another console app through the MQTT channel.

I am using the following library:

> MQTTnet.AspNetCore

**Problem:**

- The MQTT client connects only when *Console.ReadLine()* is present.

***Main function:***

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
 MQTTClass MQTT = new MQTTClass();
 string[] topics = new string[2] {
  "topicA",
  "topicB"
 };
 foreach(var topic in topics) {
  var IsConnected = MQTT.Connect(topic);
  if (IsConnected ) {
   Console.WriteLine("Topic => " + topic + " successfully connected");
  } else {
   Console.WriteLine("Topic => " + topic + " failed to connect");
  }
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
}
```

***MQTTClass:***

```
public class MQTT
{
  public IManagedMqttClient Client { get; set; }
  public bool MQTTHelper(string topic)
 {
    bool IsSuccess= false;

    var options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithClientId(xxxx)
        .WithTcpServer(xxx, xxx)
        .WithCleanSession()
        .WithTls()
        .Build();

    var managedOptions = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
        .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x))
        .WithClientOptions(options)
        .Build();

    Client = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();
    Client.StartAsync(managedOptions).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    Client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully with MQTT Brokers.");
    });
    Client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT Brokers.");
    });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(topic))
    {
        this.SubscribeAsync(topic).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    else
    {
        return false; // topic name not specified
    }
    this.Client.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
    {
        string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload);
        IsSuccess= Message(topic, message);
    });
    return IsSuccess;
}

public async Task<bool> PublishAsync(string topic, string payload, bool retainFlag = true, int qos = 1)
{
    await Client.PublishAsync(new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
        .WithTopic(topic)
        .WithPayload(payload)
        .WithQualityOfServiceLevel((MQTTnet.Protocol.MqttQualityOfServiceLevel)qos)
        .WithRetainFlag(retainFlag)
        .Build());
    return true;
}

private async Task<bool> SubscribeAsync(string topic, int qos = 1)
{
    await Client.SubscribeAsync(new TopicFilterBuilder()
        .WithTopic(topic)
        .WithQualityOfServiceLevel((MQTTnet.Protocol.MqttQualityOfServiceLevel)qos)
        .Build());

    return true;
}
private bool Message(string topic, string message)
{
      do Something;
    }
}
```

> Message(string topic, string message) function is called only when I use Console.ReadLine().     else, the program just exists.

I believe this is because MQTT failed to connect.

I have used GetAwaiter() to make sure this is not because of asynchronous programming errors.

Console.ReadLine() just suspends the main program thread through an I/O interruption.

I dont understand how Console.ReadLine() makes it work.

Comment: It seems, that it HAS to do with async programming. Without Readline the program ends before it is connected.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen can you think of any work arounds? or any direction to look at? :)

Comment: I don't know the library but I see, that you register handlers at the client object (e.g. `UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler`). The `Client.StartAsync` method seems to start a new thread running in the background and you need something to wait.

Comment: @H.G.Sandhagen true, tried awaiting the Task returned by StartAsync, but did not work. Have applied a quick hack for now -> making the main thread sleep for a second->Thread(1000);  I am feel it will have unexpected recursions at some time. Don't know if its an advisable hack though :)

Comment: What should your application do (except waiting for messages received from the server)?

Comment: It uses the message and calls a function which calls an API.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204653/discussion-between-abhilash-gopalakrishna-and-h-g-sandhagen).